# File access from sandbox in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox, nsopenpanel

Mac OS 10.12 (Sierra), Xcode 8, sandboxed MacOS app compiled for OS X 10.10. 
The scenario is next:

1. Access app's container's directory.
2. Enumerate all files inside it
3. Profit.

Then I want to access some other directory out of the container. It goes like:

1. get directory's file URL (i.e. file:///Users/whatever)

   - 1.5 if there is bookmark stored for this URL then go to 5
2. open it with Powerbox (i.e. NSOpenPanel) and confirm
3. if confirmed, make the bookmark
4. store the bookmark somewhere (I use [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults])
5. then resolve URL from that bookmark
6. call *startAccessingSecurityScopedResource* on this URL (always returns NO)
7. enumerate
8. call *stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource* on same URL

All relevant sandbox permissions are granted in app configuration file.

Strangely this routine succeeds only once on each out-of-the-container directory! on the second attempt enumeration returns empty result. I m pretty lost. Any idea?

**Update**: it looks like if I validate the URL through NSOpenPanel every time I want to access it - only then the directory can be accessed. But the whole deal of bookmarks supposed to save invocation of Powerbox on the same confirmed URLs, isnt it?

Comment: For people to have much chance of helping, beyond just guessing, you need to show the code you use (a) to get the URL, (b) create and save bookmark, and (c) restore and use bookmark - edit your question and add these details. There is nothing immediately obviously wrong with your *outline*. HTH